# Running multiple query() method in succession

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am running multiple query() methods in succession.

```
       foreach ($users as $user) {
            $sql = $this->_parseQueryVariables($sql, $user, $leaderboard);
            $results = $this->LeaderboardUsers->query($sql);
            pr($results);
        }
```

When I output the sql_dump element it lists only the first query that was executed. But the pr() in the foreach is output multiple times. Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: ok just found the answer query method caches queries by default. One has to pass false as a second parameter to avoid query caching. :)

Comment: Write that as the answer so people know it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok just found the answer query method caches queries by default.

One has to pass false as a second parameter to avoid query caching. :)

```
$results = $this->LeaderboardUsers->query($sql, false);
```